# Trying to add array keys without array values

Tags: php

Ok, so I'm trying to write something which will analyze the US Presidential candidates.

I'm trying to add all of the values up on a given day - I'm part of the way through that.

Anyway, $romlinearray - I want to have two values inside, the date, and the value for a given day. I want to insert them inside the `if ($romneydiff == 0) {` block.

What I am having a problem with is generating an array with a key name (i.e. I want to be able to do $romlinearray["value"]) and have it pull a value, but the value isn't going to be inserted until later.

How can I create an array with a key, but without a value as of yet?

```
$resultromney = mysql_query("SELECT category, value, timestamp from results where name='".$chartname2."'");
if (!$resultromney) {
    die('Invalid query, please contact administrator');
}

$posromney = 0;
$negromney = 0;
$dateromney = "1/1/2012";
$romray = array();

while ($twitromney = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultromney)) 
{

$romneytime = intval($twitromney["timestamp"]);
$romneydate = date('m/d/Y', $romneytime);
$romlinearray = array(); // THIS IS WHERE THE PROBLEM IS
$romneydiff = date_diff($dateromney, $romneytime);

$PLromney = 0;
$NLromney = 0;
$totalromney = 0;

if ($romneydiff == 0) {


switch ($twitromney["category"]) {
    case "composed":
        $PLromney = $PLromney + $twitromney["value"];
break;
    case "elated":
        $PLromney = $PLromney + $twitromney["value"];
break;
    case "clearheaded":
        $PLromney = $PLromney + $twitromney["value"];
break;
    case "agreeable":
        $PLromney = $PLromney + $twitromney["value"];
break;
    case "energetic":
        $PLromney = $PLromney + $twitromney["value"];
break;
    case "unsure":
        $NLromney = $NLromney + $twitromney["value"];
break;
    case "tired":
        $NLromney = $NLromney + $twitromney["value"];
break;
    case "depressed":
        $NLromney = $NLromney + $twitromney["value"];
break;
    case "guilty":
        $NLromney = $NLromney + $twitromney["value"];
break;
    case "confused":
        $NLromney = $NLromney + $twitromney["value"];
break;
    case "anxious":
        $NLromney = $NLromney + $twitromney["value"];
break;
    case "hostile":
        $NLromney = $NLromney + $twitromney["value"];
break;
    case "confident":
        $PLromney = $PLromney + $twitromney["value"];
break;
}
$totalromney = $PLromney - $NLromney;

$romlinearray["value"] = $totalromney + $romlinearray["value"];
}
```

Comment: Can't you just push a new key to the array using the value NULL? Eg. $my_array['new_key'] = null;

Comment: Possibly Burbas - I don't know. Is that how it is done?

Comment: I usually use false or '', but any value assigned will work. In the end, any of this options will create the slot in the array and will leave it empty. Even if you write 'empty', later you will add some value to that slot and that will be the new value